# Replacing `model.exports` with ~async~

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I am new to Nodejs, SailsJS & MongoDB,

I am writing a code for create a user in MongoDB using Sailsjs.
My code is:

```
module.exports = {
  create: function(req, res){

      var params = _.extend(req.query || {}, req.params || {}, req.body || {});

     var a = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
      a = a.toString().substring(0, 6);

      params.otp = a;

      User.create(params).exec(function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
            // res.send(500, {error: "DB Error"});
            res.json(err.status, {err: err});
            return;
          } else if (user) {
              console.log("inside ::::",user)
              return res.send(user);
          }
        });
    },
  };
```

I want to replace `module.exports` with `async`. Any suggestions please?

Comment: *"I Want to replace `module.exports` with `async`"* Why? What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: I think `mongoDB` needs some time to insert data, but the above code will redirect before it inserts.

Comment: Above code will send response only after insert is complete in mongo,because it res.send() is in callback function.
And if you want to use asynch you need to use promises first.

Comment: okay thanks @Ninad, any references ?